# How To Update Setup Version automatically with Assemblyversion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

my problem is i want to update an setup project and when i do it manually it works great, but we have a pipeline where the application gets build and gets a new Assemblyversion so i would have to change the setup version and ProductCode etc. too? Does anyone have an idea to do this?

I didnt find any soultion to do this.

Comment: You can use tools such as the MSBuild command-line tool or the WiX toolset.